# How to check the historical GC logs of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am reading the official guide of Apache IoTDB, and I found that GC log is turned off by default. Is there any problem when writing data using this setting? Aren’t the historical GC logs being discarded in this way? Are there any ways if I want to check the historical GC logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There will be a `gc.log` in the log directory of Apache IoTDB, that will store all the contents and will not be discarded. The official document to start this service means to open this log.